# Jupyter Notebook Error: Tuple index out of range

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, lstm

[I am getting this code while analyzing through lstm model. Any help will be much appreciated :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqrm7.jpg)

Comment: Please paste the code and the error. Don't paste shots of screens. :)

Comment: you should `print(X_test.shape)` before you got error

Answer (score 0):

The `tuple index out of range` happens when you try to take the second dimension of the `X_test.shape` (and I guess `X_test` is 1-dimensional).

As you know, the shape will be a tuple `(m, n)`. But if the numpy array is 1-dimensional the shape will be `(m,)`. So there isnt a second dimension. Therefore `X_test.shape[1]` will fail.